# SQL - разница между COUNT(1) и COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Какая разница между `COUNT(1)` и `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Никакой, если имеется в виду COUNT(*).

Answer (score 2):

Разницы нет. Оба варианта вернут одинаковый результат. По производительности тоже различий не будет, т.к. оптимизатор не станет преобразовывать `*` в список столбцов за ненадобностью.

PS очень рекомендую ознакомиться с [ответами по ссылке приведенной @Алексей Шиманский](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710703)

PPS [SQLFiddle (MySQL) показывающий работу `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(1)` и `count(NULL)` в случае использования `JOIN`'ов](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d2a24/2)

Comment: разве не нужно контекст рассматривать? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710703

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо за ссылку! Да, для `JOIN` не совсем понятно как поведет себя оптимизатор в случае использования `COUNT(1)`...

Comment: Вообще было бы классно перевести на русский. + то, что там в дубликате возможно. Хоть не часто такой вопрос задается, но как FAQ и эталон мог бы тут существовать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен, но времени у меня сейчас на это нет... Мне кажется еще лучще было бы перевести соответствующие "куски" из ANSI SQL-92

Comment: @MaxU с джоинами тоже будет работать правильно, если используется именно COUNT(1). В статье по ссылке кстати написано, почему нельзя использовать COUNT(something.1), поскольку семантически невозможно определить конкретный запрос в этом случае, в отличие от COUNT(something.*), который сработает корректно

Comment: @РоманДанилов, да, действительно, спасибо! Я специально проверил варианты с JOIN'ами - ссылка на SQLFiddle в ответе...

Answer (score 0):

Это два эквивалентных запроса.
Причем в MySQL если вы используете MyISAM движок, то `COUNT(*)` будет выполнен очень быстро, если используется `SELECT` из одной таблицы и нет `WHERE` условия, поскольку информация о количестве строк будет храниться в специальном хранилище.
Для COUNT(1) эта оптимизация так же сработает, но при условии, что первый столбец объявлен как `NOT NULL`.

Дополнительно можно почитать [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Comment: а при JOIN разве будет одинаковый результат?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, при JOIN тоже будет одинаковый результат. Поскольку сравнивается COUNT( * ) и COUNT(1), но не COUNT(*) и COUNT(something.1)

Comment: @РоманДанилов, вы можете объяснить связь между `COUNT(1)` и первым столбцом?

Comment: @MaxU, я добавил ссылку, там можно покопаться, думаю

Comment: @РоманДанилов, "expression:" `1` - априори `NOT NULL` и не имеет отношение к первому столбцу - собственно поэтому я и спросил...